# How to delete environment and not delete RDS on AWS elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I had an environment with PHP 5.3 and this environment had a RDS attached in the Data Tier. When I upgraded PHP version to PHP5.5 I created a new environment with a new AMI. The problem is that now I can't delete the old environment because the RDS instance is attached to it and this one will be deleted because of Deletion policy. So, someone know how to delete the old environment without delete the RDS instance?

Maybe, have I to create a RDS replica?.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not snapshot the RDS and instantiate a new RDS instance in your new environment based on that snapshot?

Comment: Adding to Mike's answer you can also use the DBDeletionPolicy option setting in the aws:rds:dbinstance namespace to control whether a snapshot is created or not on environment termination.
Read more about this option setting here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of doing so is by creating a snapshot of the instance. Then you can create a new RDS instance with the previous snapshot.

Hope this helps!